# Image not filling canvas when dims are not specified

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I would like to dynamically create a canvas, specifying the dimensions of the canvas at runtime; then I'd like to render an image over that canvas so that it fills the entire dimension of the canvas.

This works as expected, when I declare a canvas's width & height on an `<canvas>` element, as shown in this snippet (hidden by default):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h3>
    Source Image
  </h3>
  <img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/180x180">

  <h3>Canvas:</h3>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("image");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However, if I dynamically create the `<canvas>` element using Javascript, and use CSS to set the size after creating, the image will not fill the whole canvas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h3>
    Source Image
  </h3>
  <img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/180x180">

  <h3>Canvas:</h3>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
      c.style.width = "200px";
      c.style.height = "200px";
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("image");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here -- any help would be appreciated on how to get the dynamically rendered Canvas to look like the first snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `c.style.width`, you're defining a scale for displaying it on your screen (it's just CSS).

To actually set the intrinsic size of the canvas, you do this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  c.width = 200;
  c.height = 200;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<h3>Source Image</h3>
<img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/180x180">

<h3>Canvas:</h3>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

**Note:** This does not prevent you from having a different intrinsic size and display size. In fact, it's often useful if your page is displayed on a Retina screen with a high pixel density. In that case, you can have a 200x200 canvas, and set its CSS dimensions to be 100x100. That way every pixel in the canvas will be exactly 1 pixel of the screen it's displayed on.

[More info on `window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @Edward Q. Bridges: what if the placehold image is 360x360 and 180px is your design requirement? Add `img { width: 180px }` to your css and check `height / clientheight / naturalheight` in the debugger to see what happens...